# Why does Chrome Developer Tool add elements not in the file?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I have a simple HTML markup like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>lawl</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

When viewing the elements of the document, in the Chrome Deceloper Tool(F12) it looks likes this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>lawl</title>
        <style type="text/css"></style> <-- what the?
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, my question goes: Where does the style tag come from? What added it, and why?

Hope you guys can clear this up for us, it's been quite the subject the last 10 minutes in class ;-). Also worth mentioning; a class got added to a empty div in another document when the teacher tried it.

Edited title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome plugins can get access to your DOM, and so does the development tools. In this particular case, I think the development tools is the one to blame.

The empty style tag is probably a placeholder for injected CSS.

If you open the source code (`view-source:www.example.com`), you will see that your DOM is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

99:1 that the `<style>` element is a stylesheet injected by your AdBlock (or similar) extension.